# MonkeyRunner Beginner Setup Problems

Tags: python, eclipse, monkeyrunner

I have a lot of problems getting MonkeyRunner to start.
Here is my setup:  on my [android-sdk]\tools folder are following components: Python33 folder,  an APK file, a testfile called "aaa.py" (with very basic code)
OS: Windows 7

It is possible for me to debug apps on my phone with eclipse. I hope that info helps you in any way.

I added all the relevant paths to my path variable (python, tools)

I open my CMD and type in "monkeyrunner aaa.py"
And this is my CMD output.
I know all the beginner tutorials out there. And I did all the stuff they did...Nothing worked.

```
140308 04:28:10.767:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Timeout
while trying to create chimp mananger
140308 04:28:10.784:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Scri
pt terminated due to an exception
140308 04:28:10.784:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Trace
back (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Cappuccino\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\tools
\aaa.py", line 4, in <module>
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:
191)
    at com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice.<init>(AdbChimpDevice.java:7
3)
    at com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbBackend.waitForConnection(AdbBackend.jav
a:122)
    at com.android.chimpchat.ChimpChat.waitForConnection(ChimpChat.java:91)
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(MonkeyRunner.
java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException

140308 04:28:10.784:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.Py.JavaError(Py.java:495)
140308 04:28:10.784:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.Py.JavaError(Py.java:488)
140308 04:28:10.784:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:188)
140308 04:28:10.784:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:204)
140308 04:28:10.784:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems the connection between monkeyruuner and current device(adb or real device) is not established properly. This fails to return the MonkeyDevice object needed for further communication between monkeyrunner and device.

1. Make sure the virtual device is active before running this command
2. Update the adb version if this error still remains

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't test your approach but I hope others will be helped with this.